# "no firebase app ' default ' has been created - call firebase.initializeapp()" error in React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

To test FireBase, I designed a small application that sends a registration attempt to Authentication, but when I press the button in the application, I get an "no firebase app ' default ' has been created - call firebase.initializeapp()" error. Here is my code;

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text,View,Button} from 'react-native';
import auth, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'

firebase.initializeApp();

function App(){
  
  const signUp=()=>{
    
    auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('jane.doe@example.com', 'SuperSecretPassword!')
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
  }
  return(
    <View>
      <Text style={{fontSize:70}}>Hello Firebase</Text>
      <Button title='Sign Up' onPress={signUp} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

I try firebase.initializeApp(); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create your project on Firebase console.
In addition of it you have to create apps on platform specific.
Actually, you have to include google firebase config file(google-service.json for Android and GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS) in your project, so you don't need to call initializeApp function as implementing @react-native/firebase module.